# configuring grub-efi-amd64 problems

Tags: updates, dell, xps

I have a 2015 dell xps developer edition and it keeps giving me this error when it does an update. can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: I've the same problem. I've tried to update it two times and both times ubuntu software update is locked. Any progress with this issue?

Comment: In my case is even worst. When the software updater is locked (not responding) it's impossible to restart the computer.  I had to reboot via terminal and after that ubuntu is unable to start. I've had to restore ubuntu from scratch.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 5):

It seems to be that I didn't google enough before offer the bounty.

This issue is reported by dell community in [this post](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/os-applications/f/4613/t/19628766).

Following some of the advises of this thread, I've solved the problem updating software manually via terminal.

I've executed this sequence of steps:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo update-grub
```

I've been prompted to either overwrite my current `cfg` for grub or keep the old one.  We need to chose to **overwrite** it.

After this, I've executed the software updater successfully, restart, cross my fingers, and it has been worked.

Thanks for all the advises.

Comment: Mark the thread solved. This will help others facing the same problem.

Comment: Nice voodoo, but it would have helped to explain why there is an error message and why this recipe solves it.